# using scp copy file from current directory to remote machine's corresponding location without defining that full path

Tags: scp

is there way to copy file or folder to remote machine with the same address as current directory where I'm running scp from defining only file's name, eg:

```
[user@machine current_location]$scp ./file_or_folder remote:$/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `$/` is what you wish would translate to your current location? You can achieve this with

```
$ scp ./file_or_folder "remote:$(pwd)"
```

`$( cmd )` is a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). It runs the command (here `pwd` to print the current directory) and then 'replaces' itself with the command output.